# Hanging line indentation with enumerate

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate

I'm writing a multiple choice text in latex, and I've been having some problems with the identation. I successfully indented all my text using

```
\begin{enumerate}
{\setlength\itemindent{15pt}\item[1)] Select one of the following:}
\vspace{0.2cm}
{\setlength\itemindent{32pt}\item[a)] This is the answer a), which 
                                      is not true unless you know it is.}
\itemsep0em
{\setlength\itemindent{32pt}\item[b)] This is the answer b), which 
                                      is not true unless you know it is.}
\itemsep0em
{\setlength\itemindent{32pt}\item[c)] This is the answer c), which
                                      is not true unless you know it is.}
\itemsep0em
{\setlength\itemindent{32pt}\item[d)] This is the answer d), which
                                      is not true unless you know it is.}
\itemsep0em
{\setlength\itemindent{32pt}\item[e)] This is the answer e), which
                                      is not true unless you know it is.}
\end{enumerate}
```

The big problem is that the text of each possible answer of the multiple choices, after the identifying letter, is not indented with respect to the letter. In other words, I get:

```
a) This is the answer a), which
is not true unless you know it is.
```

While what I really want is:

```
a) This is the answer a), which
   is not true unless you know it is.
```

Does anyone knows how to do this? I've searched for previous answers, but none of them dealt directly with the enumerate enviorment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want to take a look through [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s documentation. That will cut out a ton of repeated code for your list formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep}
% uncomment the line below to align first-level enumerated lists along the
% left margin
% \setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\alph*}),leftmargin=0em}
% aligns second-level enumerated lists with the first-level enumerated lists

\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
\item Select one of the following:
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is the answer a), which is not true unless you know it is. This is
      the answer a), which is not true unless you know it is.
\item This is the answer b), which is not true unless you know it is. This is
      the answer b), which is not true unless you know it is.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to ommit the indentation of the second nested list?

Comment: You want level 1 and 2 enumerated lists indented to the same absolute position?

Comment: Something like that. However, I managed to do it by adding [leftmargin=NUMBERcm], where NUMBER goes according to the limits of the document :-). Maybe there's a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: See edited answer. There's an option in the code to align everything to the left margin if needed, too.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you simply nest the enumerations like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} %% for fancy stuff like itemsep..

\begin{document}
 \begin{enumerate}
\item{ Select one of the following:}
 \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0pt]
 \item{This is the answer a), which is not true unless you know it is.}
 \item{This is the answer b), which is not true unless you know it is is not true unless you know it is.}
 \item{This is the answer c), which is not true unless you know it is.}
 \item{This is the answer d), which is not true unless you know it is.}
 \item{This is the answer e), which is not true unless you know it is.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work :-(.

Comment: @Néstor: I don't follow. Please give a full MWE with details of your comment *doesn't work*

Comment: My bad, it worked. I had some libraries that didn't let the original code work :-).